# how to execute cksum unix command from java which takes parameters at runtime

Tags: java

I am trying to execute below piece of code but not getting `cksum` value. How can I get this value using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command. I have restriction to use `ProcessBuilder` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Process p;
    String strJob = "/abc/xyz/scripts/report.ksh";
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ksh","cksum ","/data/p2p/monitor/scripts/Apps_filesystem_report.ksh"});
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((str = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!"+input.readLine());
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html`  The third argument is the working directory, not a filename.

Comment: Then how can I pass the file name which check sum is required?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked.  There is a one argument version of `exec()` where you pass in a `String[]`: `public Process exec(String[] cmdarray)
Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.
Parameters:
cmdarray - array containing the command to call and its arguments.`

Comment: Even I tried below command string array but still not working.
String strCronJob = "/abc/xyz/scripts/report.ksh";
String[] cmd = {"ksh","/usr/bin/cksum ",strCronJob};
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: Why are you listing "ksh"?  The system cannot find it without the full path and /usr/bin/cksum does not need it.

Comment: I tried String[] cmd = {"cksum ",strCronJob}; but getting error 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cksum ": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)

Comment: How is Java supposed to find it?  What is the path it uses at runtime?  You are going to have to setup the Java default path, add the path as an environment variable to the exec() or use the full path to the command.  Notice in my comment I used the full path.